# How can use httpcookie with specific data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have a cookie but ı need the cookie inside UserID ,

I write in cookie UserID and ı need to be acces every page this User ID.

I can acces my cookie "response" but this data very big , I need to be just response inside User ID.

This is my code:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["response"];
        ViewData["Cookie"] = cookie;
        return View();
    }
```

I am searching this subject and find whis way,

This is new code but it is not work .

```
            var computername = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["response"].Value;
```

This is find other way but it is not work.

```
      int User_id;
        HttpCookie reqCookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["response"];
        if (reqCookies != null)
        {
            User_id = reqCookies["UserID"].ToString();
            ViewData["Cookie"] = User_id;

        }
```

How can acces UserID 53 ?

This is my cookie;

1. Kim Dağıtıcı    Ad  Değer
2. Furkan  LOCAL AUTHORITY http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier    c557cfef-fa95-4b5a-8dce-fe01bfa94737
3. List item Furkan    LOCAL AUTHORITY http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name

4.Furkan    Internal    UserID  53

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this question. It appears as though you have a large amount of data in a cookie and want to get some specific data out of it? If so, I suggest separating your data into smaller cookies, or using a different mechanism like hidden fields to hold your data.

Comment: Yes , it is. I am edit questions. it is a not very big data i think it is smaller but ı am new ı can't fixed this problem

Answer (score 0):

**First**: I can't see where you save the data in the Cookie before you want to read it's value

**Second**: Save cookie as an Object and then after receive cast it again to this object and select the property you want

I used in example **UserDTO** as my user object that holds user data

after login

```
public IActionResult Login(UserDTO user)
{
    ...

    // after validating and login success
    var cookie = new HttpCookie("response", user);
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie); // use here Response.Cookies not Request.Cookies
    ...

    return View();
}
```

---

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["response"] as UserDTO; // must be the same type when set its value
    ViewData["Cookie"] = cookie;
    return View();
}
```

and in View

```
var computername = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["response"].Value as UserDTO; // to prevent casting exception .. will return null if cast faild
if(computername != null) 
{
    computername.Name;// will return Kim 
    computername.UserId;// will return 53 
}
```